# Getting dates from week number of year in android

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am trying to get the dates from a given weeknumber and the year. The below piece of code is always showing the currentDates even though I enter week and year.

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(Locale.getDefault());
    c.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 15);
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);

    String result = "";

    int firstDayOfWeek = c.getFirstDayOfWeek();
    for (int i = firstDayOfWeek; i < firstDayOfWeek + 7; i++) {
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, i);
        result += new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd").format(c.getTime()) + "\n";
    }
```

instead of getting dates of Week number 15. I am getting current dates values always. I am not what is wrong here?

How to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: wow.. Why -1? I thought this genuine question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
  now.set(Calendar.YEAR,2015);
  now.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR,15);

  System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd").format(now.getTime()));
```

> OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: Giving wrong results.  

And also what does the code do? I have to dynamically get the dates by giving week number and the year.

Comment: first day of week depends on Locale

Comment: That is fine. but the results are coming wrong instead of Friday it is showing wedneday! Also where do insert weekValue? I require the dates for given week number of the year?

Comment: I am getting that output value but I need 7 dates. How do I get that?

Comment: seven dates of that specific `week`?

Comment: just put a increment to the first day you got, I guesss that is pretty `simple`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76332/discussion-between-yushi-and-thedevman).

Comment: That is problem. I can't do manual increment because I have check lot of things like how many days in a month and then what is next month etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

please update the my code: it's works for me.

```
  Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
      now.set(Calendar.YEAR,2015);
      now.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR,15);


      String result = "";

        int firstDayOfWeek = now.getFirstDayOfWeek();

        Log.e("day","day:"+firstDayOfWeek);
        for (int i = firstDayOfWeek; i < firstDayOfWeek + 7; i++) {
            now.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, i);
            result += new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd").format(now.getTime()) + "\n";
        }

    Log.e("result","result:"+result);
```

Comment: Are you sure it is working for you.. because I am still getting this weeks date even though I have 2015, week 4. Also what is the difference between your code and my code.

Comment: I have just changed only your code by `Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();` get calender .but i have tried above code,get correct result , like this,  `result: 2015.01.18 ,  2015.01.19 ,  2015.01.20 ,  2015.01.21 ,2015.01.22 , 2015.01.23, 2015.01.24
`

Comment: i have used the year as 2015 and week of the year as 4 , i get the above answer, then i don't know why your not get the ans.

Comment: That is interesting. I am not getting the results it is always the current dates.

Comment: please replace the normal calender like mine instead of GregorianCalendar used.